# Camel: How to stream a from SQL component using StreamList

Tags: java, database, apache-camel, streaming

I am trying to use Camels SQL component to stream from a database using outputType=StreamList. 
I get the ResultIterator from a Java class with ConsumerTemplate :

```
public Flux<String> CreateFlux () {
ConsumerTemplate consumer = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate();

    ResultSetIterator resultSetIterator = consumer.receiveBody(
            "sql:SELECT DATA FROM TRANSAKSJON WHERE REQ_ID='" + recId + "'?outputType=StreamList", ResultSetIterator.class);
    ...
    while (result.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) result.next();
        String data = map.get("DATA");

    }
}
```

I get the following error when trying to iterate the ResultsetIterator:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed [90007-197]

Upon inspection I see that the connection is closed.
connection = {HikariProxyConnection@16287} "HikariProxyConnection@1048081993 wrapping 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.ClosedConnection"

How can I use the camel SQL component to stream? I have to use it from a bean that is not inside a camel route. I see that the streaming works only if I am using the SQL component inside a camel route.

Camel version is: 2.24.1

Update1: After looking at the source code it is intended. onDone closes the conncetion. I am trying to set UnitOfWork on my defaultExchange to keep the connection open by marking the exchange as not done.

Update2: managed to get it to work by setting UnitOf Work:

```
        ProducerTemplate pTmp = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();

        DefaultExchange defaultExchange = new DefaultExchange(camelContext);
        UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new DefaultUnitOfWork(defaultExchange);
        defaultExchange.setUnitOfWork(unitOfWork);
        pTmp.send("direct:DbStream", defaultExchange);
```

The route DbStream executes the SQL select described above

Answer (score 1):

Do not use receiveBody, but just receive to get the `Exchange` back. Then you can get the iterator from its message body, and the after use, you can done the exchange (see the javadoc)

Comment: Thank you Claus Ibsen. I managed to get it to work by setting Unit Of Work. on the exchange . Will update answer.